# Does accoreconsole.exe depends on AutoCAD?

Tags: autocad, autodesk, dwg

I am new to AutoCAD API. I want to use accoreconsole.exe (AutoCAD 2016) to batch convert dwg files to pdf. Does accoreconsole.exe requires AutoCAD to be installed in the target system or I can use accoreconsole.exe(with it's dlls) in computers which does not have AutoCAD installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, AutoCAD console is part of AutoCAD (full install).

But you can use the webservice AutoCAD I/O to batch process drawings, check at http://developer.autodesk.com

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will definitely have a look into AutoCAD I/O web service. But I am still curious why accorconsole is crashing on other systems. Is it possible that it internally checks if AutoCAD is installed in the system?

Comment: AutoCAD Console is just an interface to it, it still need all the installation (file, registry, DLLs, etc) to run. In summary, you need a full install of AutoCAD in order to access AutoCAD Console.